# GroovyClassLoader Hierarchy and CompilerConfiguration

Tags: groovy

**Problem:**

- Create `GroovyClassLoader` *GCLA* with explicitly set `CompilerConfiguration`
- Create another `GroovyClassLoader` *GCLB* with different `CompilerConfiguration` that sets the `BaseScriptClass` and uses *GCLA* as parent

-> a script loaded in *GCLB* will not have the `BaseScriptClass` set correctly (but uses the potentially set basescript of *GCLA*)

**Long Story:**

My application uses four Groovy scripts to allow customization of certain actions. Each script provides a small DSL, where the DLSs are different for each script. When the action is excecuted in the application, the corresponding script will be called. Additionally some *common groovy scripts* can be loaded at application startup for storing of common data or definition of helper functions.

The scripts are heavily typechecked at the start of the application.

My first approach was to have *one* `GroovyClassLoader` which first loads the *common groovy scripts* and then does a `loadClass` for each of the scripts. The DSL is created by simply adding corresponding elements to the binding of each script befor the script is run. The `GroovyClassLoader` uses a `CompilerConfiguration` with *TypeCheck-Extensions* to typecheck the scripts.

This works quite well but has two severe limitations:

- the typechecking has to be performed based on the name of the script (because the DSLs for each script is different)
- the typechecking script gets quite complicated because it has to handle all four DSLs

To get rid of the named limitations I tried to use a distinct `GroovyClassLoader` (with my actual ClassLoader as parent) for each of the script (i. e. one per DSL) and set a corresponding `ScriptBaseClass` which provides the functionality for the DSL. This works very well: the typechecking code is reduced drastically, I can have distinct typechecking scripts for each DSL and I don't have to mess with the name of the script.

**But** I don't get this to work with the *common groovy scripts*. As soon as I try to use the `GroovyClassLoader` of the *common scripts* as parent for the `GroovyClassLoader` of the DSL scripts, the DSL no longer gets the correct `BaseScriptClass` although it's explictly set in the `CompilerConfiguration`. It seems that the child `GroovyClassLoader` uses the `BaseScriptClass` of the parent `GroovyClassLoader`.

Any ideas of how to get this working?

**UPDATE**
In my original post I did not mention that I'm using scala. Actually I tried the following code snippet:

```
val rootConfig = {
  val cf = new CompilerConfiguration(CompilerConfiguration.DEFAULT)
  cf.setSourceEncoding("UTF-8")
  cf.addCompilationCustomizers(new ASTTransformationCustomizer(classOf[CompileStatic]))
  cf
}

val childConfig = {
  val cfg = new CompilerConfiguration(CompilerConfiguration.DEFAULT)
  cfg.setSourceEncoding("UTF-8")
  cfg.setScriptBaseClass("NonExisting")
  cfg.addCompilationCustomizers(new ASTTransformationCustomizer(classOf[CompileStatic]))
  cfg
}

val rootGCL = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass.getClassLoader, rootConfig, false)
val childGCL = new GroovyClassLoader(rootGCL, childConfig, false)
```

This does not work and the child ClassLoader seems to ignore the `CompilerConfiguration` completely: it does not complain about the non-exiting `BaseScriptClass` and if I switch off the static-compilation in the rootConfig it will not even perform the static checks.

**If I move the ClassLoader creation to a Java file everything works as expected**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GroovyClassLoader has several constructor. For example one for ClassLoader and one for GroovyClassLoader. The GroovyClassLoader version will take the configuration from it. But if you do for example `new GroovyClassLoader((ClassLoader) parent)` or go with giving the configuration yourself. And for that it is even enough to give null as configuration. The constructor logic will take CompilerConfiguration.DEFAULT then to configure the GroovyClassLoader: `new GroovyClassLoader(parent,null)` and if you want to be very sure no strange paths are added to the GroovyClassLoader, use the variant with a boolean `new GroovyClassLoader(parent,null,false)`

Comment: The root cause of the problem seems to be related to my scala code, which was not present in my original post. Your post helped me to find a working solution, so I accept it as answer. Thanks!

Comment: The cause of the problem is actually using `loadClass` on the ClassLoader. It will not handle the BaseScripts as described in my original question. Using `parseClass` works correctly.